# Public-Key -or- Password & Google Authenticator for SSH Login

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, google-authenticator

I found an article (http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/) that explains how to configure OpenSSH to ask for a Google Authenticator code upon a successful login.

Is it possible to configure OpenSSH so that the following happens:

- If the user has the correct private key to login to the server, log the user in.
- If the user doesn't have a private key allowed to login to the server, ask the user for the account's password AND for a Google Authenticator code.

This would be convenient (since on my computers I would only need the private key) and secure (since I could leave password authentication enabled and safe).

Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible to configure an `sshd` to require **either** a valid keypair **or** use HOTP (new one-time password (OTP) on each request) OATH-based authentication - I'm doing it.  I'm fairly sure that Google Authenticator is just another OATH implementation.

My full writeup can be read at http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/yubikey-oath.html, but the upshot is:

Assuming your `sshd` is already set up to allow public-key based authentication (most are), add these two lines to `sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Install `pam_auth` (this being the CentOS-oriented way, for x86_64):

```
yum install pam_oath
ln -s /usr/lib64/security/pam_oath.so /lib64/security/
```

Make the authentication file `/etc/users.oath`, mode `600`, owner `root:root`, and populate it with lines like:

```
#type   username        pin     start seed
HOTP    fred            -       123a567890123b567890123c567890123d567890
```

Edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and add the line

```
auth required pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=5 digits=8
```

Skip the `digits=8` if you're happy with 6-digit HOTP OATH.  I believe a similar method can be used for TOTP OATH (new OTP every *n* seconds), but I'm using hardware OATH tokens instead of software ones, and they're yubikeys, which only do HOTP OATH.

The only wrinkle is that when you ssh in without presenting a valid key, it asks for the OATH code **before** the password.  I couldn't make it work the other way around, but decided I didn't care all that much; the prompts make it pretty clear which token is being requested.

Answer (score 4):

You need to append:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
```

without a comma between `publickey` and `keyboard-interactive` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. All other settings do not have to be altered (as long as the configuration is equal to the given howtogeek tutorial).